# How try catch order is executed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Given the *test* function, why the code from **finally** code is first executed rather then the one from the **try** block ? If so, the variable **a** has a new value of 5 ( from line 9 ) and then should have a new value of 8 ( from line 4 ). But it hasn't, the value of **a** is 6. Somehow only the logs are executed from **finally** block and assignments are ignored ? It's a bad practice to use **return** in **try-catch** blocks ? I see that in many popular frameworks the catch and finally blocks lack of **return** statement.

```
1    function test () {
2      window['a'] = 3; 
3      try {
4        window['a'] += 3;
5        return window['a'];
6      } 
7      catch(e) {} 
8      finally { 
9        window['a'] = 5;
10       console.log('finally');
11      }
12    }
13
14    console.log(test());
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function test() {
  window['a'] = 3;
  try {
    window['a'] += 3;
    return window['a'];
  } catch (e) {} finally {
    window['a'] = 5;
    console.log('finally');
  }
}

console.log(test());
```

**Output expected**

---

> 6
>
> finally

**Execution output**

---

> finally
>
> 6

Comment: 6 is the return of function test(),normally it should be at the last if there is no asynchronous code

Comment: How try...catch...final works is, final will run once try/catch execution completes. So when you do `return ...` in try, first, execution of try is completed and then execution of function. Hence, final statement is executed before returning value. I guess confusion is because you have a `return` statement. But if you give a thought, both `throw` and `return` works in a similar way. They break flow. So if you expect it to be handled, so will be `return`.

Comment: @Teemu Your fiddle does not log the result of `test()`. (That log was added later)

Comment: @Rajesh Ouch, indeed. There's was too many things going on simultaneously on my side, hence the mistake ... But as I've already stated, and the docs says, "finally is always executed", that seems to be really true in every case, even in case of `return` in the try block.

Comment: @Teemu I can imagine. Work and SO together can be difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course of normal execution, the `finally` block is *guaranteed* to get executed after a `try` block. If an exception is thrown in the `try` block, then the order is try -> catch -> finally. In your code, even though we have a return statement as the last line in the try block, the finally block gets executed before exiting the method.

An example of when the `finally` block won't get executed is if the current thread is killed off while the try block is still running.

---

**EDIT**: From ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification section [13.15.8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-try-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
TryStatement : try Block Finally
Let B be the result of evaluating Block.
Let F be the result of evaluating Finally.
If F.[[type]] is normal, let F be B.
If F.[[type]] is return, or F.[[type]] is throw, return Completion(F).
If F.[[value]] is not empty, return Completion(F).
Return Completion{[[type]]: F.[[type]], [[value]]: undefined, [[target]]: F.[[target]]}.
```

Therefore, if a `finally` block executes normally, the result of `try-finally` block remains unchanged. This is why `finally` block should be used only for cleanup tasks and it should not contain any business logic.

Comment: "In your code, even though we have a return statement as the last line in the try block, the finally block gets executed before exiting the method." so...why window.a value is not 8 ?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The execution order is TRY then CATCH then FINALLY (as usual).

You are returning the value in try block, so that why you have that output.

The try block is executed, then the finally one (because there are no errors), and it logs your message, then the function result is returned.

If you put console.log(window['a']) instead of return, you will see your expected output.

Comment: I'd expect `return` to leave the function immediately, nevertheless the pending `finally` statement ..?

Comment: Those are the general rules for try-catch-finally block execution:
- When no exception occurs, the finally block will execute after the try.
- If an uncaught exceptions occurs, like when we divide by zero, the finally block will execute before we are thrown out of the method.
- If we execute a return from the try block, the finally block still executes before we leave.

Comment: But in OP's code the `try` block has a return statement and no errors. Notice, that OP gets the log from `finally` first, then the returned value. Which is not actually reproducable, I can get only "finally" logged. The docs says, that "_finally is always executed_", hence it seems to override even the `return` statement too.

Comment: @Teemu I have added a snippet in the question that shows the output. I also tried to explain in comment. Please check

Comment: If we execute a return clause from the try block, the finally block still executes before we leave. - that's a rule
The log is appear as the first occurrence, because "6" represents the result of the function (the returned value), and test function returns the result after executes the finally block

Comment: so...why window.a value is not 8 ?